# Proper way to resend messages to topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, faust

I load messages from kafka topic to database. Loading to database can fail. Also I do not want to lose unsent messages.

App code:

```
import faust

app = faust.App('App', broker='kafka://localhost:9092')

source_topic = app.topic('source_topic')
failed_channel = app.channel()  # channel for unsent messages


@app.agent(source_topic)
async def process(stream):
    async for batch in stream.take(100_000, within=60):
        # here we have not info about partitions and keys
        # to reuse them when resending if sending failed
        try:
            pass  # send to database.  can fail
        except ConnectionError:
            for record in batch:
                # sending to channel is faster than sending to topic
                await failed_channel.send(value=record)


@app.agent(failed_channel)
async def resend_failed(stream):
    async for unsent_msg in stream:
        await source_topic.send(value=unsent_msg)
```

Maybe there is more standart way to handle such situations? Adding app.topic('source_topic', acks=False) works only after restarting app.

Answer (score 1):

> I load messages from kafka topic to database
>
> Maybe there is more standart way to handle such situations

Yes - it's called Kafka Connect :-)

The standard pattern is to do any processing on your data and write it [back to] Kafka topics. Then you use the Kafka topic as a source for a Kafka Connect sink connector, in this case the [Kafka Connect JDBC Sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html).

Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, and handles restarts, scaleout, failures, etc etc.

See also [Kafka Connect in Action: JDBC Sink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-3qN_tlYR4)